# Pygame, I want to make it play the sound

Tags: python, pygame

How to make this work. I want it to play audio once the rectangle cross the center of the screen.

```
import pygame
from pygame import*

pygame.init()
mixer.init()

win=pygame.display.set_mode((600,00))
pygame.display.set_caption("bla")

x=20
y=20

width=10
height=10

run=True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event == pygame.QUIT:
            run= False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys [pygame.K_LEFT] :
        x-=4
    if keys [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x+=4
    if keys [pygame.K_UP]:
        y-=4
    if keys [pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y+=4

    if 350 < x < 450 and 350 < y < 450:
        mixer.music.load('music.wav')
        mixer.music.play(0)




    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(300,300),(10))
    pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

I expect the sound will play when the rectangle cross the center of the window. But instead nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo:

```
win=pygame.display.set_mode((600,00))
#                                ^^^^
```

I guess should be:

```
win=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
```

To test you code, you may add a gray rectangle area to show where the cursor should enter to start the music, so you can be sure where you have to place the cursor.

```
win.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(win, (100, 100, 100), (350, 350, 100, 100)) #this is the rectagle where the music starts
pygame.draw.circle(win,(255,0,0),(300,300),(10))
pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0),(x,y,width,height))
pygame.display.update()
```

Actually is not really at the center of the screen, so maybe you need to adjust the coordinates. Reduce x and y by 100 to center it in a 600x600 screen.

Note also that until the cursor remains in the area you will not hear anything because actually you start the music each iteration. Sort of  rewinding the music each iteration.
But when you exit the area, it will start. To make it start when you enter in the square, check if the music is already playing and start it only if nothing is playing:

```
if 350 < x < 450 and 350 < y < 450:
    if not mixer.music.get_busy():
        mixer.music.load('music.wav')
        mixer.music.play(0)
```

[pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.get_busy) checks if the music is playing.